# Is there any hope to get the result faster if we use a supercomputer for the given problem?

Tags: matrix, programming, date-and-time, wolfram-alpha-queries, system-limitations

If an operation in Mathematica (say, computing the determinant of a $88\times88$ parametric matrix) takes much time to be computed on a **personal computer (core i7)**, say a week, then, is there any hope that using a **supercomputer** get the result faster? Is this running time related to Mathematica's limitation or the computer we are running Mathematica on it?

My matrix $M$ is sparse and `ArrayRules[SparseArray[M]]` is as follows. Can someone please make comment on how I can ask Mathematica to compute its determinant faster?

```
sp:={{1, 1} -> -E^(-((I x)/2)) - E^(-((I x)/2)) x, {1, 
   2} -> -E^(((I x)/2)) + E^((I x)/2) x, {1, 3} -> 1 - x, {1, 4} -> 
  1 + x, {2, 3} -> -1 - x, {2, 4} -> -1 + x, {2, 5} -> 
  1 + x, {2, 6} -> 
  1 - x, {3, 5} -> -1 + x, {3, 6} -> -1 - x, {3, 7} -> 
  1 + x, {3, 8} -> 1 - x, {4, 1} -> 
  E^(-((I x)/2)) - E^(-((I x)/2)) x, {4, 2} -> 
  E^((I x)/2) + E^((I x)/2) x, {4, 7} -> -1 + x, {4, 8} -> -1 - x, {5,
    9} -> -E^(((I x)/2)) + E^((I x)/2) x, {5, 10} -> -E^(-((I x)/2)) -
    E^(-((I x)/2)) x, {5, 11} -> 1 + x, {5, 12} -> 
  1 - x, {6, 11} -> -1 + x, {6, 12} -> -1 - x, {6, 13} -> 
  E^(-((I x)/2)) - E^(-((I x)/2)) x, {6, 14} -> 
  E^((I x)/2) + E^((I x)/2) x, {7, 13} -> -E^(-((I x)/2)) - 
   E^(-((I x)/2)) x, {7, 14} -> -E^(((I x)/2)) + E^((I x)/2) x, {7, 
   15} -> 1 - x, {7, 16} -> 1 + x, {8, 9} -> 
  E^((I x)/2) + E^((I x)/2) x, {8, 10} -> 
  E^(-((I x)/2)) - E^(-((I x)/2)) x, {8, 15} -> -1 - x, {8, 
   16} -> -1 + x, {9, 17} -> -E^(-((I x)/2)) - E^(-((I x)/2)) x, {9, 
   18} -> -E^(((I x)/2)) + E^((I x)/2) x, {9, 19} -> 1 - x, {9, 20} ->
   1 + x, {10, 19} -> -1 - x, {10, 20} -> -1 + x, {10, 21} -> 
  E^((I x)/2) + E^((I x)/2) x, {10, 22} -> 
  E^(-((I x)/2)) - E^(-((I x)/2)) x, {11, 21} -> -E^(((I x)/2)) + 
   E^((I x)/2) x, {11, 22} -> -E^(-((I x)/2)) - E^(-((I x)/2)) x, {11,
    23} -> 1 + x, {11, 24} -> 1 - x, {12, 17} -> 
  E^(-((I x)/2)) - E^(-((I x)/2)) x, {12, 18} -> 
  E^((I x)/2) + E^((I x)/2) x, {12, 23} -> -1 + x, {12, 24} -> -1 - 
   x, {13, 25} -> -E^(((I x)/2)) + E^((I x)/2) x, {13, 
   26} -> -E^(-((I x)/2)) - E^(-((I x)/2)) x, {13, 27} -> 
  1 + x, {13, 28} -> 
  1 - x, {14, 27} -> -1 + x, {14, 28} -> -1 - x, {14, 29} -> 
  E^(-((I x)/2)) - E^(-((I x)/2)) x, {14, 30} -> 
  E^((I x)/2) + E^((I x)/2) x, {15, 29} -> -E^(-((I x)/2)) - 
   E^(-((I x)/2)) x, {15, 30} -> -E^(((I x)/2)) + E^((I x)/2) x, {15, 
   31} -> 1 - x, {15, 32} -> 1 + x, {16, 25} -> 
  E^((I x)/2) + E^((I x)/2) x, {16, 26} -> 
  E^(-((I x)/2)) - E^(-((I x)/2)) x, {16, 31} -> -1 - x, {16, 
   32} -> -1 + x, {17, 33} -> -E^(-((I x)/2)) - E^(-((I x)/2)) x, {17,
    34} -> -E^(((I x)/2)) + E^((I x)/2) x, {17, 35} -> 
  1 - x, {17, 36} -> 
  1 + x, {18, 35} -> -1 - x, {18, 36} -> -1 + x, {18, 37} -> 
  E^((I x)/2) + E^((I x)/2) x, {18, 38} -> 
  E^(-((I x)/2)) - E^(-((I x)/2)) x, {19, 37} -> -E^(((I x)/2)) + 
   E^((I x)/2) x, {19, 38} -> -E^(-((I x)/2)) - E^(-((I x)/2)) x, {19,
    39} -> 1 + x, {19, 40} -> 1 - x, {20, 33} -> 
  E^(-((I x)/2)) - E^(-((I x)/2)) x, {20, 34} -> 
  E^((I x)/2) + E^((I x)/2) x, {20, 39} -> -1 + x, {20, 40} -> -1 - 
   x, {21, 41} -> -E^(((I x)/2)) + E^((I x)/2) x, {21, 
   42} -> -E^(-((I x)/2)) - E^(-((I x)/2)) x, {21, 43} -> 
  1 + x, {21, 44} -> 
  1 - x, {22, 43} -> -1 + x, {22, 44} -> -1 - x, {22, 45} -> 
  E^(-((I x)/2)) - E^(-((I x)/2)) x, {22, 46} -> 
  E^((I x)/2) + E^((I x)/2) x, {23, 45} -> -E^(-((I x)/2)) - 
   E^(-((I x)/2)) x, {23, 46} -> -E^(((I x)/2)) + E^((I x)/2) x, {23, 
   47} -> 1 - x, {23, 48} -> 1 + x, {24, 41} -> 
  E^((I x)/2) + E^((I x)/2) x, {24, 42} -> 
  E^(-((I x)/2)) - E^(-((I x)/2)) x, {24, 47} -> -1 - x, {24, 
   48} -> -1 + x, {25, 49} -> -E^(-((I x)/2)) - E^(-((I x)/2)) x, {25,
    50} -> -E^(((I x)/2)) + E^((I x)/2) x, {25, 51} -> 
  1 - x, {25, 52} -> 
  1 + x, {26, 51} -> -1 - x, {26, 52} -> -1 + x, {26, 53} -> 
  E^((I x)/2) + E^((I x)/2) x, {26, 54} -> 
  E^(-((I x)/2)) - E^(-((I x)/2)) x, {27, 53} -> -E^(((I x)/2)) + 
   E^((I x)/2) x, {27, 54} -> -E^(-((I x)/2)) - E^(-((I x)/2)) x, {27,
    55} -> 1 + x, {27, 56} -> 1 - x, {28, 49} -> 
  E^(-((I x)/2)) - E^(-((I x)/2)) x, {28, 50} -> 
  E^((I x)/2) + E^((I x)/2) x, {28, 55} -> -1 + x, {28, 56} -> -1 - 
   x, {29, 65} -> -E^(-((I x)/2)) - E^(-((I x)/2)) x, {29, 
   66} -> -E^(((I x)/2)) + E^((I x)/2) x, {29, 67} -> 
  1 - x, {29, 68} -> 
  1 + x, {30, 67} -> -1 - x, {30, 68} -> -1 + x, {30, 69} -> 
  E^((I x)/2) + E^((I x)/2) x, {30, 70} -> 
  E^(-((I x)/2)) - E^(-((I x)/2)) x, {31, 69} -> -E^(((I x)/2)) + 
   E^((I x)/2) x, {31, 70} -> -E^(-((I x)/2)) - E^(-((I x)/2)) x, {31,
    71} -> 1 + x, {31, 72} -> 1 - x, {32, 65} -> 
  E^(-((I x)/2)) - E^(-((I x)/2)) x, {32, 66} -> 
  E^((I x)/2) + E^((I x)/2) x, {32, 71} -> -1 + x, {32, 72} -> -1 - 
   x, {33, 81} -> -1 - x, {33, 82} -> -1 + x, {33, 83} -> 
  1 - x, {33, 84} -> 
  1 + x, {34, 83} -> -1 - x, {34, 84} -> -1 + x, {34, 85} -> 
  E^((I x)/2) + E^((I x)/2) x, {34, 86} -> 
  E^(-((I x)/2)) - E^(-((I x)/2)) x, {35, 85} -> -E^(((I x)/2)) + 
   E^((I x)/2) x, {35, 86} -> -E^(-((I x)/2)) - E^(-((I x)/2)) x, {35,
    87} -> 1 + x, {35, 88} -> 1 - x, {36, 81} -> 1 - x, {36, 82} -> 
  1 + x, {36, 87} -> -1 + x, {36, 88} -> -1 - x, {37, 
   57} -> -E^(((I x)/2)) + E^((I x)/2) x, {37, 
   58} -> -E^(-((I x)/2)) - E^(-((I x)/2)) x, {37, 59} -> 
  1 + x, {37, 60} -> 
  1 - x, {38, 59} -> -1 + x, {38, 60} -> -1 - x, {38, 61} -> 
  E^(-((I x)/2)) - E^(-((I x)/2)) x, {38, 62} -> 
  E^((I x)/2) + E^((I x)/2) x, {39, 61} -> -E^(-((I x)/2)) - 
   E^(-((I x)/2)) x, {39, 62} -> -E^(((I x)/2)) + E^((I x)/2) x, {39, 
   63} -> 1 - x, {39, 64} -> 1 + x, {40, 57} -> 
  E^((I x)/2) + E^((I x)/2) x, {40, 58} -> 
  E^(-((I x)/2)) - E^(-((I x)/2)) x, {40, 63} -> -1 - x, {40, 
   64} -> -1 + x, {41, 73} -> -E^(((I x)/2)) + E^((I x)/2) x, {41, 
   74} -> -E^(-((I x)/2)) - E^(-((I x)/2)) x, {41, 75} -> 
  1 + x, {41, 76} -> 
  1 - x, {42, 75} -> -1 + x, {42, 76} -> -1 - x, {42, 77} -> 
  E^(-((I x)/2)) - E^(-((I x)/2)) x, {42, 78} -> 
  E^((I x)/2) + E^((I x)/2) x, {43, 77} -> -E^(-((I x)/2)) - 
   E^(-((I x)/2)) x, {43, 78} -> -E^(((I x)/2)) + E^((I x)/2) x, {43, 
   79} -> 1 - x, {43, 80} -> 1 + x, {44, 73} -> 
  E^((I x)/2) + E^((I x)/2) x, {44, 74} -> 
  E^(-((I x)/2)) - E^(-((I x)/2)) x, {44, 79} -> -1 - x, {44, 
   80} -> -1 + x, {45, 65} -> 1, {45, 66} -> 
  1, {45, 73} -> -1, {45, 74} -> -1, {46, 65} -> 
  I x, {46, 66} -> -I x, {46, 73} -> -I x, {46, 74} -> 
  I x, {47, 49} -> 1, {47, 50} -> 
  1, {47, 57} -> -1, {47, 58} -> -1, {48, 49} -> 
  I x, {48, 50} -> -I x, {48, 57} -> -I x, {48, 58} -> 
  I x, {49, 61} -> -1, {49, 62} -> -1, {49, 69} -> 1, {49, 70} -> 
  1, {50, 61} -> -I x, {50, 62} -> I x, {50, 69} -> 
  I x, {50, 70} -> -I x, {51, 1} -> 1, {51, 2} -> 
  1, {51, 9} -> -1, {51, 10} -> -1, {52, 1} -> 
  I x, {52, 2} -> -I x, {52, 9} -> -I x, {52, 10} -> 
  I x, {53, 13} -> -1, {53, 14} -> -1, {53, 21} -> 1, {53, 22} -> 
  1, {54, 13} -> -I x, {54, 14} -> I x, {54, 21} -> 
  I x, {54, 22} -> -I x, {55, 17} -> 1, {55, 18} -> 
  1, {55, 25} -> -1, {55, 26} -> -1, {56, 17} -> 
  I x, {56, 18} -> -I x, {56, 25} -> -I x, {56, 26} -> 
  I x, {57, 33} -> 1, {57, 34} -> 
  1, {57, 41} -> -1, {57, 42} -> -1, {58, 33} -> 
  I x, {58, 34} -> -I x, {58, 41} -> -I x, {58, 42} -> 
  I x, {59, 45} -> 1, {59, 46} -> 
  1, {59, 53} -> -1, {59, 54} -> -1, {60, 45} -> 
  I x, {60, 46} -> -I x, {60, 53} -> -I x, {60, 54} -> 
  I x, {61, 29} -> -1, {61, 30} -> -1, {61, 37} -> 1, {61, 38} -> 
  1, {62, 29} -> -I x, {62, 30} -> I x, {62, 37} -> 
  I x, {62, 38} -> -I x, {63, 77} -> 1, {63, 78} -> 
  1, {63, 85} -> -1, {63, 86} -> -1, {64, 77} -> 
  I x, {64, 78} -> -I x, {64, 85} -> -I x, {64, 86} -> 
  I x, {65, 5} -> -E^(I t - (I x)/2), {65, 6} -> -E^(
   I t + (I x)/2), {65, 81} -> E^((I x)/2), {65, 82} -> 
  E^(-((I x)/2)), {66, 5} -> -I E^(I t - (I x)/2) x, {66, 6} -> 
  I E^(I t + (I x)/2) x, {66, 81} -> 
  I E^((I x)/2) x, {66, 82} -> -I E^(-((I x)/2)) x, {67, 67} -> 
  E^((9 I d \[Pi])/11 + (I x)/2), {67, 68} -> 
  E^((9 I d \[Pi])/11 - (I x)/2), {67, 71} -> -E^(
   I b - (9 I d \[Pi])/11 - (I x)/2), {67, 72} -> -E^(
   I b - (9 I d \[Pi])/11 + (I x)/2), {68, 67} -> 
  I E^((9 I d \[Pi])/11 + (I x)/2) x, {68, 
   68} -> -I E^((9 I d \[Pi])/11 - (I x)/2) x, {68, 71} -> -I E^(
   I b - (9 I d \[Pi])/11 - (I x)/2) x, {68, 72} -> 
  I E^(I b - (9 I d \[Pi])/11 + (I x)/2) x, {69, 83} -> E^(
  I d \[Pi] + (I x)/2), {69, 84} -> E^(
  I d \[Pi] - (I x)/2), {69, 87} -> -E^(
   I b - I d \[Pi] - (I x)/2), {69, 88} -> -E^(
   I b - I d \[Pi] + (I x)/2), {70, 83} -> 
  I E^(I d \[Pi] + (I x)/2) x, {70, 84} -> -I E^(
   I d \[Pi] - (I x)/2) x, {70, 87} -> -I E^(
   I b - I d \[Pi] - (I x)/2) x, {70, 88} -> 
  I E^(I b - I d \[Pi] + (I x)/2) x, {71, 3} -> 
  E^((I d \[Pi])/11 + (I x)/2), {71, 4} -> 
  E^((I d \[Pi])/11 - (I x)/2), {71, 7} -> -E^(
   I b - (I d \[Pi])/11 - (I x)/2), {71, 8} -> -E^(
   I b - (I d \[Pi])/11 + (I x)/2), {72, 3} -> 
  I E^((I d \[Pi])/11 + (I x)/2) x, {72, 
   4} -> -I E^((I d \[Pi])/11 - (I x)/2) x, {72, 7} -> -I E^(
   I b - (I d \[Pi])/11 - (I x)/2) x, {72, 8} -> 
  I E^(I b - (I d \[Pi])/11 + (I x)/2) x, {73, 11} -> -E^(
   I b - (2 I d \[Pi])/11 - (I x)/2), {73, 12} -> -E^(
   I b - (2 I d \[Pi])/11 + (I x)/2), {73, 15} -> 
  E^((2 I d \[Pi])/11 + (I x)/2), {73, 16} -> 
  E^((2 I d \[Pi])/11 - (I x)/2), {74, 11} -> -I E^(
   I b - (2 I d \[Pi])/11 - (I x)/2) x, {74, 12} -> 
  I E^(I b - (2 I d \[Pi])/11 + (I x)/2) x, {74, 15} -> 
  I E^((2 I d \[Pi])/11 + (I x)/2) x, {74, 
   16} -> -I E^((2 I d \[Pi])/11 - (I x)/2) x, {75, 19} -> 
  E^((3 I d \[Pi])/11 + (I x)/2), {75, 20} -> 
  E^((3 I d \[Pi])/11 - (I x)/2), {75, 23} -> -E^(
   I b - (3 I d \[Pi])/11 - (I x)/2), {75, 24} -> -E^(
   I b - (3 I d \[Pi])/11 + (I x)/2), {76, 19} -> 
  I E^((3 I d \[Pi])/11 + (I x)/2) x, {76, 
   20} -> -I E^((3 I d \[Pi])/11 - (I x)/2) x, {76, 23} -> -I E^(
   I b - (3 I d \[Pi])/11 - (I x)/2) x, {76, 24} -> 
  I E^(I b - (3 I d \[Pi])/11 + (I x)/2) x, {77, 27} -> -E^(
   I b - (4 I d \[Pi])/11 - (I x)/2), {77, 28} -> -E^(
   I b - (4 I d \[Pi])/11 + (I x)/2), {77, 31} -> 
  E^((4 I d \[Pi])/11 + (I x)/2), {77, 32} -> 
  E^((4 I d \[Pi])/11 - (I x)/2), {78, 27} -> -I E^(
   I b - (4 I d \[Pi])/11 - (I x)/2) x, {78, 28} -> 
  I E^(I b - (4 I d \[Pi])/11 + (I x)/2) x, {78, 31} -> 
  I E^((4 I d \[Pi])/11 + (I x)/2) x, {78, 
   32} -> -I E^((4 I d \[Pi])/11 - (I x)/2) x, {79, 35} -> 
  E^((5 I d \[Pi])/11 + (I x)/2), {79, 36} -> 
  E^((5 I d \[Pi])/11 - (I x)/2), {79, 39} -> -E^(
   I b - (5 I d \[Pi])/11 - (I x)/2), {79, 40} -> -E^(
   I b - (5 I d \[Pi])/11 + (I x)/2), {80, 35} -> 
  I E^((5 I d \[Pi])/11 + (I x)/2) x, {80, 
   36} -> -I E^((5 I d \[Pi])/11 - (I x)/2) x, {80, 39} -> -I E^(
   I b - (5 I d \[Pi])/11 - (I x)/2) x, {80, 40} -> 
  I E^(I b - (5 I d \[Pi])/11 + (I x)/2) x, {81, 43} -> -E^(
   I b - (6 I d \[Pi])/11 - (I x)/2), {81, 44} -> -E^(
   I b - (6 I d \[Pi])/11 + (I x)/2), {81, 47} -> 
  E^((6 I d \[Pi])/11 + (I x)/2), {81, 48} -> 
  E^((6 I d \[Pi])/11 - (I x)/2), {82, 43} -> -I E^(
   I b - (6 I d \[Pi])/11 - (I x)/2) x, {82, 44} -> 
  I E^(I b - (6 I d \[Pi])/11 + (I x)/2) x, {82, 47} -> 
  I E^((6 I d \[Pi])/11 + (I x)/2) x, {82, 
   48} -> -I E^((6 I d \[Pi])/11 - (I x)/2) x, {83, 51} -> 
  E^((7 I d \[Pi])/11 + (I x)/2), {83, 52} -> 
  E^((7 I d \[Pi])/11 - (I x)/2), {83, 55} -> -E^(
   I b - (7 I d \[Pi])/11 - (I x)/2), {83, 56} -> -E^(
   I b - (7 I d \[Pi])/11 + (I x)/2), {84, 51} -> 
  I E^((7 I d \[Pi])/11 + (I x)/2) x, {84, 
   52} -> -I E^((7 I d \[Pi])/11 - (I x)/2) x, {84, 55} -> -I E^(
   I b - (7 I d \[Pi])/11 - (I x)/2) x, {84, 56} -> 
  I E^(I b - (7 I d \[Pi])/11 + (I x)/2) x, {85, 59} -> -E^(
   I b - (8 I d \[Pi])/11 - (I x)/2), {85, 60} -> -E^(
   I b - (8 I d \[Pi])/11 + (I x)/2), {85, 63} -> 
  E^((8 I d \[Pi])/11 + (I x)/2), {85, 64} -> 
  E^((8 I d \[Pi])/11 - (I x)/2), {86, 59} -> -I E^(
   I b - (8 I d \[Pi])/11 - (I x)/2) x, {86, 60} -> 
  I E^(I b - (8 I d \[Pi])/11 + (I x)/2) x, {86, 63} -> 
  I E^((8 I d \[Pi])/11 + (I x)/2) x, {86, 
   64} -> -I E^((8 I d \[Pi])/11 - (I x)/2) x, {87, 75} -> -E^(
   I b - (10 I d \[Pi])/11 - (I x)/2), {87, 76} -> -E^(
   I b - (10 I d \[Pi])/11 + (I x)/2), {87, 79} -> 
  E^((10 I d \[Pi])/11 + (I x)/2), {87, 80} -> 
  E^((10 I d \[Pi])/11 - (I x)/2), {88, 75} -> -I E^(
   I b - (10 I d \[Pi])/11 - (I x)/2) x, {88, 76} -> 
  I E^(I b - (10 I d \[Pi])/11 + (I x)/2) x, {88, 79} -> 
  I E^((10 I d \[Pi])/11 + (I x)/2) x, {88, 
   80} -> -I E^((10 I d \[Pi])/11 - (I x)/2) x, {_, _} -> 0}
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/140088/discussion-on-question-by-charmin-is-there-any-hope-to-get-the-result-faster-if).

Answer (score 3):

It's not so much about a supercomputer but about using the right tools. As pointed out in the comments, a SparseMatrix should be significantly faster:

```
s=SparseArray[yourMatrix,{88,88}];
Det[s]
```

Comment: Thanks, then I should run this new command and see how long it will take to compute it.

Comment: it gives error that the matrix is not square.

Comment: @charmin, provide ``SparseArray`` the actual dimensions of your matrix: ``s = SparseArray[matrix, {88, 88}]``

Comment: @Domen Then, does this help? Is not it the same as computing the determinant of my original matrix?

Comment: You complained that Mathematica  _gives error that the matrix is not square_. My comment is meant to solve this problem by explicitly making the matrix be square.

Comment: From the documentation, "Det[m] gives the determinant of the square matrix m." From Wiki, "In mathematics, the determinant is a scalar value that is a function of the entries of a square matrix."

Comment: @Domen you are right but my question was general that is if the answer given by "infinitezero" is different from (or can be done faster than) the original matrix. Since to me (as a beginner in Mathematica) it seems that `SparseArray[MyMatrix,{88,88}]=MyMatrix`

Comment: The matrix is the same but the way Mathematica calculates and represents it internally it is different

Comment: @infinitezero Thanks. I ran this code yesterday and it is still running.

Comment: @charmin can you upload the whole matrix somewhere? Maybe at [pastebin](https://pastebin.com/)

Comment: @infinitezero My whole matrix $M$ can be determined by this code `M = SparseArray[sp, {88, 88}] // MatrixForm` where $sp$ is given in the code in the question.